# getting Blank response from php server while access from other country in android

Tags: java, android, connection, httpresponse

I made a andoid application in which I am getting response from php server, requesting in POST format. I am using below code for http connection:

```
// random string as boundary for multi-part http post
    String strBoundary = "3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f";
    String endLine = "\r\n";

    OutputStream os;

    String url = encodeUrl(methodType, graphURL, params);
    Log.d("url - ",url);


    Log.d("Method Type - ", methodType + " URL - " + url);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
            .openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);

    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", System.getProperties()
            .getProperty("http.agent"));


    if (!methodType.equals("GET")) {
        Bundle dataparams = new Bundle();
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            if (params.getByteArray(key) != null) {
                dataparams.putByteArray(key, params.getByteArray(key));
            }
        }

        // use method override
        if (!params.containsKey("method")) {
            params.putString("method", methodType);
        }

        if (params.containsKey("access_token")) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            String decoded_token = URLDecoder.decode(params
                    .getString("access_token"));
            params.putString("access_token", decoded_token);
        }

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + strBoundary);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.connect();

        os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        os.write(("--" + strBoundary + endLine).getBytes());
        os.write((encodePostBody(params, strBoundary)).getBytes());
        os.write((endLine + "--" + strBoundary + endLine).getBytes());

        if (!dataparams.isEmpty()) {
            for (String key : dataparams.keySet()) {                    
                os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\""
                        + key + "\"" + endLine).getBytes());
                os
                        .write(("Content-Type: content/unknown" + endLine + endLine)
                                .getBytes());
                os.write(dataparams.getByteArray(key));
                os.write((endLine + "--" + strBoundary + endLine)
                        .getBytes());
            }
        }
        os.flush();
    }

    String response = "";
    try {
        response = parseXmlSvn(conn.getInputStream());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error Stream contains JSON that we can parse to a FB error
        //response = read(conn.getErrorStream());
        Log.i("RESPONSE",""+response);
    }
    Log.i("RESPONSE", ""+response);
    return response;
```

Everything is working fine on my demo server, I uploaded my PHP service to clients server. I am getting proper response from his server also.
But when client access app in 3G or 4G in some other country in his android devices, he is getting Blank response while the same service of same server can be accessible in iOS code easily by him. Is it some packet loss while getting response or any other problem?

I would really appreciate any help you can give me.
Thanks

Comment: what country, not Turkey is it?

Comment: Wrong tag, does not look like PHP.

Comment: in canada.In android devices ,Checked in 5-6 devices,he is not getting response

Comment: @Str looks more like java

Comment: @Str I dont know, but maybe its because in the other side it is a php server